# What does 나근나근 말하다 mean?

Tags: vocabulary

What does the phrase '나근나근 말하다' mean?

From OP comment:

it (the phrase) was on a tv show and they did put a (?) next to what the girl said since it clearly was off. here it is! 조사랑: 되게 나근나근(?)하게 말씀하시는데

Comment: where did you see this and can you add a sample sentence?

Comment: it was on a tv show and they did put a (?) next to what the girl said since it clearly was off.  here it is! 조사랑: 되게 나근나근(?)하게 말씀하시는데....

Comment: please add details such as these when asking your question. It is better to have as much details about your problem as possible to help others help you.

Comment: People use a (?) to show that something before it is uncertain or could be wrong. 나근나근 is incorrect but it is what 조사랑 has said. The correct pronunciation of 나긋나긋하게 is 나근나그타게 (not 나근나근하게).

Answer (score 3):

Most likely it is [나긋나긋](https://ko.dict.naver.com/detail.nhn?docid=6571200):

> 사람을 대하는 태도가 매우 상냥하고 부드러운 모양.

Apparently [나근나근](https://ko.dict.naver.com/detail.nhn?docid=6571000) is a different word:

> 가늘고 긴 물건이 자꾸 보드랍고 탄력 있게 움직이는 모양.

Of course, with these kinds of words, people can just apply them to new situations or mix up similar words, so it's always a bit fuzzy.  But I think 나긋나긋 is probably the commonly used term here.

Comment: it was on a tv show and they did put a (?) next to what the girl said since it clearly was off.  here it is! 조사랑: 되게 나근나근(?)하게 말씀하시는데....

Answer (score 3):

It's really obvious that it must be "나긋나긋" not 나근나근(I haven't seen this word actually used in my life)
This expression is commonly used together with the word "말하다"(speaking, talking, and saying), often taking the form "나긋나긋하게 말하다".

It means the manner of speech(tone, voice, and the attitude of a speaker) is super gentle. It doesn't necessarily have any negative meaning to it since it's quite positive-neutral. But still, it is used for describing a feminine tone.

Comment: SO did the Korean girl say it incorrectly on purpose or did she get the two confused?? Is that a common mistake ??

Answer (score 2):

나근 나근 : representing the moving of a long and flexible thing

나뭇 가지가 바람에 나근 거린다.

Branches of the tree is flexible by a wind.

나근 나근한 목소리

flexible voice : It is a voice which is tender, not speedy, not
 loud, vivid, honeyed and euphonious. Consider the situation when sister reads a
 book for her brother.

Comment: it was on a tv show and they did put a (?) next to what the girl said since it clearly was off.  here it is! 조사랑: 되게 나근나근(?)하게 말씀하시는데....